# Finding the angle and distance over a ggplot/grid in R

Tags: r, math, ggplot2, r-grid

I have made a ggplot using some A and B numeric values. (If possible can you give me the solution for grid too?)
Such as:

```
A   B
2   3
3   7
4   8
5   9
6   2
7   1
```

Now from the points, lets say A1 and A2 as shown in diagram, I want to measure the angle and the distance covered from each point.

I know how to calculate the distance (via euclidean distance formula) from one point and for angle it can be calculated as cross and dot product of the vectors. But I am facing the problem to code this and to represent it.
Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Do you want to calculate these and put them in the plot as per your drawing? I think so, but that is not what you say.

Comment: @MikeWise I think "...and to represent it." means exactly that.

Comment: Could be. But I could interpret it otherwise too. Would be easy for the OP to confirm it. If this is a didactic geometry plot of some sort I think `grid` might be a better platform than `ggplot`

Comment: @MikeWise Yes, I do want to represent it. If you can represent it its the best. and that's what I am looking for. But even if you can find the distance and the angles its good.!

Comment: Please post the code you have used so far and the resulting ggplot output as a bitmap. That will help too.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, I do think that grid is better but I can't find the solution for grid too..

Comment: @MikeWise From the given dataset itself I have plot a simple ggplot. and used geom_path() for the path. Sorry, I don't have the code right now. But can you just write for this angle and distance thing? I code for the above is just a single liner ggplot(data, aes( ) + geom_path()).. it was something like this.

Comment: Hmm, don't have time to do it right now. Might get around to it later this evening if someone has not beat me to it.

Comment: And please post your code and the results. Otherwise you are likely to get downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a first pass - doing it in `grid`. This could be done in `ggplot2` too I imagine, but I want to learn grid for now since ggplot2 and lattice are based on it. This plot has some issues, for example the angle of the annotation text really has to be calculated in device coordinates, not native coordinates, so it only looks right if your grid squares are really square. I might fix that later, but I don't have time now. Also I would think I could specify the defaults so that each primitive doesn't have that `default.units` parameter. This should get you started though.

```
library(grid)

grid.newpage()
df <- data.frame(a=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),b=c(3,7,8,9,2,1))

vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=0.999,height=0.999,xscale=c(0,1),yscale=c(0,1))
pushViewport(vp)

# a rectangle (with dashed lines) on the border of the viewport:
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty="dashed",col="steelblue"))

vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=0.9,height=0.9,xscale=c(0,8),yscale=c(0,10),
               default.units="native")
pushViewport(vp)

#draw the background grid
grid.polyline(x=rep(0:8,each=2),y=rep(c(0,10),9),id=rep(1:9,each=2),
              gp=gpar(lty="solid",col="gray"),default.units="native")
grid.polyline(x=rep(c(0,8),11),y=rep(0:10,each=2),id=rep(1:11,each=2),
              gp=gpar(lty="solid",col="gray"),default.units="native")

# add the lables
grid.text(as.character(0:8),x=0:8,y=rep(-0.2,9),
          gp=gpar(col="gray",fontsize=12),default.units="native")
grid.text(as.character(0:10),y=0:10,x=rep(-0.2,11),
          gp=gpar(col="gray",fontsize=12),default.units="native")

grid.lines(x=df$a,y=df$b,gp=gpar(col="steelblue"),default.units="native")
grid.points(x=df$a,y=df$b,gp=gpar(col="steelblue"),default.units="native")


for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
   x0 <- df$a[i]
   y0 <- df$b[i]
   x1 <- df$a[i+1]
   y1 <- df$b[i+1]
   dx <- x1-x0
   dy <- y1-y0
   dist <- sqrt( dx^2 + dy^2 )
   ang <- (180/3.14159)*atan2(dy,dx)
   txt <- sprintf("D: %.1f  Ang:%.1f",dist,ang)
   xt <- (x0+x1)/2
   yt <- (y0+y1)/2 + 0.2*abs(dy/dx)
   grid.text(txt,x=xt,y=yt,rot=ang,
             gp=gpar(col="steelblue",fontsize=9),default.units="native")
}
```

[image]

Comment: @MikeWise can you give the similar answer if my grid is not square?

Comment: The angle measurement and calculation really only makes sense if the grid is square, or more exactly, if the underlying measurements are rotation invariant. Think about it...

Comment: @MikeWise what if I need some dynamic grid? I have a similar set of problem but I am importing multiple CSVs. In that case my grid should not remain static as you have done i.e., it should change its xscale and yscale as per the dataset..!
Can you give some solution to this?

Comment: The easiest way is to allocate a square area - the biggest you can, at the start of your script (like I do here). Then make sure your x and y scales are the same (unlike I do here) - i.e. xmin and ymin and xmax and ymax should be equal. Then everything will always be square.

Comment: Otherwise you need to figure out how much room you have in x and y, subtract the margins you allocate from that space, and make sure your xmax-xmin, and your ymax-ymin are in the same ratio as what is left in that space.

Comment: @MikeWise I still have the problem in making the squares.. Can you please view this kindda dataset? 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475657/how-to-make-the-scales-dynamic-in-grid-in-r)

Comment: Probably best you just simplify your request to the essentials and post a new question.

Comment: Wonder who downvoted me here... Actually someone took a vote away. Have I been bad? Odd... @Fairy - I might look at your question tomorrow, but too tired for now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds easier to calculate those angles and distances outside the plot,

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),
                y=c(3,7,8,9,2,1))

d2 <- with(d, data.frame(dx=diff(x), dy=diff(y)))
d2 <- mutate(d2, distance = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2), 
             angle = atan2(dy, dx))

ann <- mutate(cbind(d[-nrow(d),], d2), 
              x=x+dx/2, y=y+dy/2, 
              label = sprintf("%.2f\n %2.f degrees", 
                              distance, angle*180/pi))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = ann, vjust = 0,
            aes(x, y, label=label, angle=angle*180/pi)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: I am having problem in adjusting the text in the plot. It does appear same when I use this dataset. But when I use my original dataset, the -ve x-axis text appears upsite down and quite far away frm the base line..

Comment: do yourself a favour and post a fully reproducible minimal example of your problem. Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark, every time.