# How can I produce a dataset adjustable grid in R?

Tags: r, grid

I have a question regarding grid in R. I am importing my datasets using CSV files. Each file consist of similar column but have varying data values.

Now I want to write a general code for grid, which can adjust its view (scales, height & width) according to the dataset.

I tried to set the min and max values of the column as variables but its not working and showing me error. How can I modify this code to produce a general plot which can plot for all CSV files having same 'a' and 'b' columns but different values. Here's the code for single dataset CSV to make grid:

```
grid.newpage()
df <- data.frame(a=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),b=c(3,7,8,9,2,1))

vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=0.999,height=0.999,xscale=c(0,1),yscale=c(0,1))
pushViewport(vp)

# a rectangle (with dashed lines) on the border of the viewport:
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty="dashed",col="steelblue"))

vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=0.9,height=0.9,xscale=c(0,8),yscale=c(0,10),
           default.units="native")
pushViewport(vp)

#draw the background grid
grid.polyline(x=rep(0:8,each=2),y=rep(c(0,10),9),id=rep(1:9,each=2),
          gp=gpar(lty="solid",col="gray"),default.units="native")
grid.polyline(x=rep(c(0,8),11),y=rep(0:10,each=2),id=rep(1:11,each=2),
          gp=gpar(lty="solid",col="gray"),default.units="native")
```

I tried to see the native option for grid but I didn't understand it well enough!

Comment: why do you want to proceed with raw grid commands? It's much easier with higher level graphics packages, such as lattice or ggplot2. In fact, if you try hard enough you'll end up rewriting good chunks of them.

Comment: @baptiste I have original in ggplot. But I am facing a problem in that due to that I tried to go for grid.!
The original plot that I want to produce is :

**Finding the angle and distance between points over a ggplot**

Comment: @baptiste Can you give the solution for any of the problems.

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't really understand.. do you have a link to the original issue with ggplot2?

Comment: @baptiste you can refer to the following 

[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424222/finding-the-angle-and-distance-over-a-ggplot-grid-in-r)